# How to use tag {%include example.html%} Stencil with Swift

Tags: swift, stencils, kitura

I embedded template Stencil in my project (Kitura https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura ,template engine Stencil https://github.com/kylef/Stencil#include). I don't understand how to use tag `{% include "comment.html" %}`.
my example , but not work.

example.stencil.html

```
<html>
      <head>
            hello example
            {% include "include.stencil.html" %}
      </head>
</html>
```

include.stencil.html

```
<b>I'm here</b>
```

code swift

```
import Stencil 

let pathTemp=Path("include.stencil.html")
let context = Context(dictionary: ["loader": TemplateLoader(paths: [pathTemp])])
do {
    let template = try Template(named: fileName)
    let rendered = try template.render(context)
    return rendered 
}catch
{
    return "Error:\(error)"
}
```

> Error :Error:'include.stencil.html' template not found in
>   ../include.stencil.html

How to use it, help me plz. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's because you have included your filename in the path. The path should be just the path to the file's location, excluding the name of the file itself.

```
let pathTemp=Path("/path/to/my/file/")
```